# app gets force close while adding items to listview (android)

Tags: java, android, listview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use an existing database with an Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/how-to-use-an-existing-database-with-an-android-application)

I have to add items to listview by using arrayadapter in android so done the coding, my xml layout file name is "jobs", but i'm getting error as "jobs cannot be resolved or is not a field", i had inlucded this activity in manifest but still same error

```
public class Jobs extends ListActivity {
private TextView selection;

private static final String[] items={"Computer Hardware", "Featured", "Information Technology", "Software", "Technical"

};
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.jobs);
    ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.jobs, items);
        setListAdapter(adapter);    


 }
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id)
{
    selection.setText(items[position]);
}
 }
```

This is xml layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/selection"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.rebuix.com"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/rebuix"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
    android:background="#3D0909">
    <activity
        android:name=".LoadingScreen"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_loading_screen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Rebuix"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_rebuix" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.rebuix.com.Rebuix" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".com.rebuix.com.Jobs"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Login"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.rebuix.com.Rebuix" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".About"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_about" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Home"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Changepassword"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_changepassword" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity" />
    </activity>
   </application>

   </manifest>
```

logcat output

```
01-31 12:31:53.133: I/Tutorial(531): Starting task with url: www.google.co.uk
01-31 12:32:03.972: D/dalvikvm(531): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 64K, 52% free  2595K/5379K, external 1645K/2137K, paused 52ms
01-31 12:32:04.102: D/dalvikvm(531): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 2K, 52% free 2594K/5379K, external 2687K/3355K, paused 45ms
01-31 12:32:08.083: D/AndroidRuntime(531): Shutting down VM
01-31 12:32:08.083: W/dalvikvm(531): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
01-31 12:32:08.103: E/AndroidRuntime(531): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-31 12:32:08.103: E/AndroidRuntime(531): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.exm.com/com.exm.com.Jobs}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
01-31 12:32:08.103: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1405)
01-31 12:32:08.103: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
01-31 12:32:08.103: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
01-31 12:32:08.103: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
01-31 12:32:08.103: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at com.rebuix.com.Rebuix$4.onClick(Rebuix.java:69)
01-31 12:32:08.103: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
01-31 12:32:08.103: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
01-31 12:32:08.103: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-31 12:32:08.103: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-31 12:32:08.103: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 01-31 12:32:08.103: E/AndroidRuntime(531):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
 01-31 12:32:08.103: E/AndroidRuntime(531):     at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-31 12:32:08.103: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-31 12:32:08.103: E/AndroidRuntime(531):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
 01-31 12:32:08.103: E/AndroidRuntime(531):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
  01-31 12:32:08.103: E/AndroidRuntime(531):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post the error message.

Answer (score 3):

because you are extending `ListActivity` then declare ListView is as in xml:

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

and get ListView reference as :

```
ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

OR

```
   ListView list = this.getListView();
```

Comment: now error in the place of id got cleared but my app gets force close if i run it.

Comment: @DDA : because you are not initializing textView

Comment: @DDA : put  `selection = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.selection);` after setContentView

Comment: but stil it gets force close, i have defined that in manifest... i hav posted my stack trace, pls can u see that

Comment: @DDA : change `android:name=".jobs"` to `android:name="com.exm.com.Jobs"` in manifest

Comment: i had given in capitals also but stil it get force close

Comment: @DDA :if still crashing then post new log in question when it's crashing

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is:

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.jobs, items);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Remove android:

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.jobs, items);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: i had added that activity in manifest it get force close when i run it

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
public class Jobs extends ListActivity {



 private TextView selection;

private static final String[] items = { "Computer Hardware", "Featured", "Information Technology",
        "Software", "Technical"

};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.jobs);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

}

public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    selection.setText(items[position]);
}
```

}

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/selection"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

***Explanation :***

**1** )  So you list in the custom view should be having id android:id="@android:id/list".  If you want to add them in a **ListActivity** .

**2** ) You don't map the Items to list-view, rather to list-items. So you have to use either a custom list item or use the android default while adding  **new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);**

Comment: android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 ?? i have given my layout name as "jobs" so y should i give "simple_list_item"?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
android.R.layout.jobs
```

use

```
R.layout.jobs
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have used the wrong R class. You are referring to your jobs definition as `android.R.layout.jobs` (which is Android's  R class and probably doesn't contain a jobs definition). This should be something like `<your package>/R.layout.jobs`.

Answer (score 0):

May your problem is: `android.R.layout.jobs`

In

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.jobs, items);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Try it :

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
```

Answer (score 0):

As your extending your activity by ListActivity then you must need to declare listview id as `@android:id/list`

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

in your activity there is no need to declare listview. or otherwise if you want to declare then do as follows

```
ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not that hard to notice the error, pay attention to the stack trace when you're getting errors.

> 01-31 12:32:08.103: E/AndroidRuntime(531): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.exm.com/com.exm.com.Jobs}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: The stack trace pasted above says otherwise. Could you paste the manifest code as well?

Comment: i had pasted that too above the stack trace code. @Janitha

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, I meant the whole manifest file.

Comment: now i have pasted the entire manifest file @JanithaR

Comment: Replace this `<activity
        android:name=".com.rebuix.com.Jobs"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >` with this `<activity
        android:name=".Jobs"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >` and see.